# Flask-SQLAlchemy integration test clear database after each test with foreign key constraints

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I want to know how to write fast integration tests with `flask-sqlalchemy` and `unittest`, without having to create and drop tables on each test. I am using Postgres as my database.

Right now, the tables are created and dropped in `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` respectively, which is fine from a performance standpoint. What I need is a way to delete all data and "reset" the database in each individual test, without re-creating all tables.

The closest I have gotten is with this code, but it raises an `IntegrityError` due to foreign key constraints.

```py
def tearDown(self):
    meta = db.metadata
    for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
        db.session.execute(table.delete())

    db.session.commit()
```

Important note: Since I am doing integration tests, I inevitably hit `db.session.commit` in my application code, which invalidates any session transaction, so I have not been able to use that as a solution.

Comment: Could you use an in-memory database such as H2 (https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) for your tests? It won't necessarily be fully compatible with postgres, but if you're only using the basic features it can be good enough. If not, then I'd suggest that you write your tests in a way to ensure no conflicts. You could either generate a unique key each time you run your test suite, or you could clear the database once after all the tests have run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
    db.session.execute(f"TRUNCATE {table.name} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;")
```

The `CASCADE` does the trick here, from the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-truncate.html):

```
Automatically truncate all tables that have foreign-key references to any of the named tables, or to any tables added to the group due to CASCADE.
```

So it tells the postgres to remove all rows that points to rows in truncated table.

On the other hard, `RESTART IDENTITY`:

```
Automatically restart sequences owned by columns of the truncated table(s).
```

Makes your autoincrement columns start from the beginning.

Comment: Oh nice, this works! Would you mind adding a little explanation to your answer as to what `RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE` does?

Comment: @DariusCosden Added little explanation, hope it helps!